# Why this command does not work in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am a Jenkins beginner.

Why does this command work?

```
sed -i -E s/'image: '(.*)${stack_name}-${service_name}:.*\$/'image: '\1${stack_name}-${service_name}:${version}/g
```

And why does the same command not work when it is included in a Jenkinsfile?

```
sh "sed -i -E s/'image: '(.*)${stack_name}-${service_name}:.*\$/'image: '\1${stack_name}-${service_name}:${version}/g"
```

The error is:

```
/opt/jenkins_data/workspace/secuview-front_master-Z2ADTSIGTSEJOG3UYRU4FPDUF5VZMB3SMQLEOUD46TUZG4POWKYQ@tmp/durable-a484faaf/script.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood Jenkinsfiles are essentially Apache Groovy scripts, therefore [string escaping rules](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_escaping_special_characters) for Groovy apply. When you have slashes they need to be escaped (e.g. `\` -> `\\`) and when you're using double quotes using `${}` literals actually [get interpreted](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string) by the script instead of being passed to the shell step.

Try this instead:

```
sh 'sed -i -E s/\'image: \'\\(.*\\)${stack_name}-${service_name}:.*\\$/\'image: \'\\1${stack_name}-${service_name}:${version}/g'
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried with your suggestions. And I also tried with the syntax sh """ ...... """. Without success, I have the same error.

Comment: Looks like you may have to escape the `(` and `)` as well because bash is trying to interpret them after Groovy passes it off. I've edited my answer to include escaping around those.

Comment: Tanks again Michael.